# how to find html file in ngDialog template with webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webpack, ng-dialog

Hello I have a problem while trying to use webpack to bunlde my files and ngDialog to get a popup to work. the popup will only show a "Hello!" message right now.

This is my function:

```
function popupEditOptions(){
    ngDialog.open({
        template: 'src/req/edit/editOptions.html',
        scope: $scope
    });
};
```

When i do this i get an error with: 
GET http://localhost:3000/src/req/edit/editOptions.html 404 (Not Found)

I can require the html file like this:

```
function popupEditOptions(){
    ngDialog.open({
        template: require('src/req/edit/editOptions.html'),
        scope: $scope
    });
};
```

But now i get this error that writes out the content of the html file:  
GET http://localhost:3000/Hello! 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You are missing the path of **editOptions.html**. Review and correct it.

Comment: The path to the file is correct **src/req/edit/editOptions.html**.  it even shows in the second error.

Comment: What is the path of your index.html file *(where ng-app is defined)*.

Comment: its in the root directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it may be an bug in ngDialog, referenceing to this github question:https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/issues/390.

But you can get it to work by using the `plain:true` property.

```
ngDialog.open({
   plain: true,
   template: require('src/req/edit/editOptions.html'),
   scope: $scope
});
```